# Trouble passing variable through segue (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a variable called `correctAnswers = 0` at the top of my program, I have a function where every time it is called it adds 1 to the `correctAnswers` value. I tested that the function was actually changing the variable by making it print after every +1 and sure enough it goes 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on. However I have an end screen that shows the results after the program has reached its limit of questions (10 in this case)

EDIT #2: Here is my prepare for segue function

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "EndScreenSegue") {
        let secondViewController = segue.destination as! EndScreen
        correctAnswers = sender as! Int
        secondViewController.gso = self
    }
}
```

And here is the code in my end screen:

```
var gso: GameScreen?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    gso = GameScreen()
    print(gso?.correctAnswers ?? 100)

}
```

When I print correct Answers it is still 0.

EDIT #3 I also tried this method of passing it through a segue and it is always nil. Does the fact its not working have anything to do with the fact the variable is being changed in a function? thats the only reason I can possibly think of to explain why nothing is working.

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "EndScreenSegue") {
        let secondViewController = segue.destination as! EndScreen
        secondViewController.recievedAnswers = correctAnswers
    }
}

class EndScreen: UIViewController{

    var recievedAnswers: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(recievedAnswers!)

    }
}
```

EDIT #4 Figured it out! I think.
It appears they changed prepareForSegue and it no longer works, yet xcode does not give you an error? Should another post be made about this??
Code that actually works:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "EndScreenSegue"{
        let secondViewController = segue.destination as! EndScreen
        secondViewController.recievedAnswers = correctAnswers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new instance of GameScreen in the viewDidLoad method of your EndScreen view controller. You need to pass the GameScreen object from your previous view controller to this one.

Comment: `func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "EndScreenSegue") {
            let secondViewController = segue.destination as! EndScreen
            correctAnswers = sender as! Int
            secondViewController.correctAnswers = correctAnswers
        }
    }` I did this and correctAnswers is always nil

Answer (score 0):

In your segue you're setting the `correctAnswers` property of your `EndScreen` view controller, but you're printing the value of `gso?.correctAnswers`. A new `gso` was just instantiated prior to this print statement and (I'm assuming) has a default value of 0 which is why you're getting 0 printed out.

You either need to pass the `GameScreen` through the segue (assuming that you're segueing from `GameScreen`), like so:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "EndScreenSegue") {
        let secondViewController = segue.destination as! EndScreen
        correctAnswers = sender as! Int
        secondViewController.gso = self
    }
}
```

Or you can just pass the `correctAnswers` through the segue as you're doing but be sure to use that value, not `gso?.correctAnswers`

```
class EndScreen: UIViewController{

    var correctAnswers: Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(correctAnswers ?? 100)
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I added your code, and tried it with the gso = gameScreen() and without. Both times it isn't passing the value over to the new view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of GameScreen.

Delete this line `gso = GameScreen()` from viewDidLoad

Comment: I did that and it just provides the default value instead of 0.

Comment: its a very very long file, what are you specifically looking for? I can tell you the correctAnswers variable is declared at the top to equal 0 and then i have a function where every time it is called it adds +1 to the correctAnswers variable. I should also note that i am not redeclaring the variable inside of the function i am adding to the already existing variable.

Comment: @RichardParker I think the issue is from the GameScreen class and not the prepareForSegue

Comment: When i did prepare(for segue) it worked, I think they might have changed prepareForSegue or something, because I don't think the code was doing anything.

Comment: @RichardParker I think I figured out the problem in your original post correctAnswers = sender as! Int         secondViewController.gso = self now you where passing self to the secondView controller and self if not a GameScreen object. That why it was always printing nil. It's not an issue of prepare for segue

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it looks like prepareForSegue no longer works, yet xcode does not give an error when you use it. The correct format now is:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "EndScreenSegue"{
        let secondViewController = segue.destination as! EndScreen
        secondViewController.recievedAnswers = correctAnswers
    }
}
```